# A possible typo in Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra, second edition

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is what is printed on [page 4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/anjp/textbook.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjoiqS5kvHjAhVlmuYKHZYgAJQQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2HBs11RtD3vaHB4_d5CP01):

> ...we select $m$ scalars $c_1,...,c_m$, multiply the $j$th equation by $c_j$ and then...

On page 3, the author defined a system(1-1) and with reference to that system, introduced the concept of Linear Combination on page 4. Shouldn't it be the $i$th equation instead of $j$th and $c_i$ instead of $c_j$?

Comment: What's the difference?  Perhaps the context surrounding that quote differentiates between $i,j$ but from the excerpt it just looks like $j$ is a dummy index.

Comment: Let $i=j$......

Comment: @Randall I'm so sorry. It's on page 4. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/anjp/textbook.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjoiqS5kvHjAhVlmuYKHZYgAJQQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2HBs11RtD3vaHB4_d5CP01), on page 3, they defined a system(1-1). With reference to that system, they introduced the concept of Linear Combination on page 4.